# Extract data based on a time series column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an annual daily timeseries pixel data in a data frame in such a way that each date occurs multiple times for each of the pixel. Now I would like to extract/subset this data based on a set of `dates` stored in another data frame. How can I do this in `R` using `dplyr`?

Sample data

```
X  Y  T        Value
X1 Y1 1/1/2004 1
X2 Y2 1/1/2004 2
X3 Y3 1/1/2004 3
X1 Y1 1/2/2004 4
X2 Y2 1/2/2004 5
X3 Y3 1/2/2004 6
X1 Y1 1/3/2004 7
X2 Y2 1/3/2004 8
X3 Y3 1/3/2004 9
```

Dates of interest

```
1/1/2004
1/2/2004
```

Code

```
library(dplyr)

X = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X1", "X2", "X3")
Y = c("Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "Y1", "Y2", "Y3")
T = c("1/1/2004", "1/2/2004", "1/3/2004", "1/1/2004", "1/2/2004", "1/3/2004","1/1/2004", "1/2/2004", "1/3/2004")
Value = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
df = data.frame(X, Y, T, Value)

# Desired dates
TS = read.csv("TS.csv")
TS
"1/1/2004", "1/2/2004"
#stuck...___
```

Comment: What's the logic to getting those two days

Comment: @U12-F̉͋̅̾̇orward, further analysis

Answer (score 1):

If your `TS` is `TS = c("1/1/2004", "1/2/2004")`, simply using `filter`,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(T %in% TS)

   X  Y        T Value
1 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     1
2 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     2
3 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     4
4 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     5
5 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     7
6 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     8
```

if your `TS` is `TS = ("1/1/2004, 1/2/2004")`

```
library(stringr)

df %>%
  filter(T %in% str_split(gsub("\\s+", "", TS), ",", simplify = TRUE))
```

Comment: I am getting an empty data frame with the first method. TS = ("1/1/2004", "1/2/2004")

Comment: @Mandalorian What is your `TS`? Both methods have different `TS` input.

Comment: It turns out my original time series is a `dataframe` and the values are in `character` format just like the `df ` `dataframe`. So that's why the first method is not working. How can I fix that? Should I edit my question to reflect this?

Comment: @Mandalorian That would be much helpful and get much easier to solve your problems.

Comment: Done, if it still does not help then I can share the files with you.

Comment: @Mandalorian I guess it's problem of your `TS.csv`. It may not separated into cell inside csv file, those dates are just one large chunk.(if my second method works)

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
> df[df$T %in% TS,]
   X  Y        T Value
1 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     1
2 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     2
4 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     4
5 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     5
7 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     7
8 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     8
>
```

If `TS` is
`"1/1/2004, 1/2/2004"`, use `stringr`:

```
> df[df$T %in% stringr::str_split(TS, ", ", simplify=TRUE),]
   X  Y        T Value
1 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     1
2 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     2
4 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     4
5 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     5
7 X1 Y1 1/1/2004     7
8 X2 Y2 1/2/2004     8
>
```

Comment: I don't know why I am getting an empty data frame when `TS = c("1/1/2004", "1/2/2004")`

Comment: @Mandalorian Use the first solution then

Comment: Yes, that's what I used.

Comment: @Mandalorian What does `head(unique(df$T), 5)` output?

Comment: it's `character(0)`

Comment: @Mandalorian Sorry `head(unique(df$T), 5)`

Comment: Yes, it's `character(0)`

Comment: @Mandalorian How about `df$T`

Comment: It's `"1/1/2004" "1/2/2004" "1/3/2004"`

Comment: @Mandalorian How about `TS`

Comment: It's `"1/1/2004" "1/2/2004"`

Comment: @Mandalorian What does `class(TS)` give?

Comment: it's `"character"`

Comment: I figured it out, the original dates of interest are in a `data frame` as `character`, how should I go about that?

Comment: @Mandalorian Does it work?

Comment: No if `TS` is in a `dataframe`, it does not work

Comment: @Mandalorian How about if you make `TS` a vector, like `df[df$T %in% as.vector(TS),]`

Comment: @Mandalorian Btw. If Park's answer works, mine would for sure work as well... Why is his accepted?

Comment: But then `df$T` is `character`, yes sorry I unchecked it, I mean both answers work if `TS` is not a `dataframe`. But as it turs my original timeseries of interest are from a `CSV` in a `dataframe` in the form of `character`.