# In R data.table conditionally remove rows based on elements in other columns with multiple conditions

Tags: r, data.table

How do I remove rows in a data.table based on rows in that data.table?
Reproduceable Example:

To create the Data.table run this

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Subject=c("A","A","B","B"), Test=c("TEST_A","TEST_A","TEST_A","TEST_A"), Folder=c("D1","Screen","D1","Screen"), Date=as.Date(c("2001-10-22","2001-10-23","2001-10-23","2001-10-25")))
DT[3, Date := NA]
DT
```

This is a small example of a very large dataset
Here is my logic: For every SUBJECT Remove all rows where TEST_A & folder "D1" has no date but TEST_A & Folder "Screen" has  a date.
I know I can just write an if statement, but I am trying to keep this using only data.table for readability.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69879754/extract-data-based-on-a-time-series-column-in-r) can help?

Comment: Your data returns an error while creating the `DT` object, `Error in rep(c("TEST_A"), 4:3) : invalid 'times' argument`.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy, sorry I corrected the error

Comment: Your date column has no `NAs`.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy, you have to run DT[Test == "TEST_A", Date := "na"] to complete the simulation

Comment: So you want to remove the rows that have no `date` right?

Comment: @Ed_Gravy yes but only for TEST_A

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247892/discussion-between-pan-dora-and-ed-gravy).

Comment: You start with your `Date` _column_ being `Date` _class_, which is meaningful. Then you corrupt it by choosing to assign `"na"` to some values. `"na"` is very different from `NA`, is that what you meant?

Comment: Check again folks I eliminate that part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
DT[, .SD[ !(any(is.na(Date) & Test == "TEST_A" & Folder == "D1") && 
            any(!is.na(Date) & Test == "TEST_B" & Folder == "Screen")), ], by = Subject]
```

Your sample data does not contain the conditions you specified, so this does nothing *here* but should work with more representative data.

---

Here is some sample data that includes two subjects: one with a valid D1 (dates provided) and one an invalid D1 (no date).

```r
DT <- data.table(Subject=c("A","A","B","B"), Test=c("TEST_A","TEST_B","TEST_A","TEST_B"), Folder=c("D1","Screen","D1","Screen"), Date=as.Date(c("2001-10-22","2001-10-23","2001-10-23","2001-10-25")))
DT[3, Date := NA]
DT
#    Subject   Test Folder       Date
#     <char> <char> <char>     <Date>
# 1:       A TEST_A     D1 2001-10-22
# 2:       A TEST_B Screen 2001-10-23
# 3:       B TEST_A     D1       <NA>
# 4:       B TEST_B Screen 2001-10-25
```

And the code above (unchanged):

```r
DT[, .SD[ !(any(is.na(Date) & Test == "TEST_A" & Folder == "D1") && 
             any(!is.na(Date) & Test == "TEST_B" & Folder == "Screen")), ],
    by = Subject]
#    Subject   Test Folder       Date
#     <char> <char> <char>     <Date>
# 1:       A TEST_A     D1 2001-10-22
# 2:       A TEST_B Screen 2001-10-23
```

Comment: I have edited the question so that the data set is reproducible

Comment: @PanDora, it's still the same data.

Comment: @PanDora, your data still does not reflect the condition you're trying to meet. Please create data that includes at least one subject that should be removed and one subject that should be retained, and then explicitly provide what the output should be. As it stands, your question is a good _start_ but answering it requires inference and more guesses than I'm going to put into it atm. Good luck.

Comment: And again ... adding `NA`s and adding `"na"`s are two completely different things. R will never infer that `"na"` (or any string) should be interpreted as its `NA`, and anything that looks for `NA` will never match `"na"` in resilient (or reputable) fashion.

Comment: Ok thank you for showing me how to ask the question, however your solution still does not work. You have eliminated SUBJECT B at screen

Comment: @r2evans I have edited the question again to help

Comment: @PanDora: first, please do not edit somebody's answer and add "DOES NOT WORK" into the answer. In fact, editing somebody else's answer should be avoided unless you know you are **adding value**, not adding commentary. Second, you have yet to provide a reproducible question that clearly shows how this does not answer how your question at least at some point was phrased. If this does not work, you need to better explain: give us data, run this code, show its output, and clearly explain how this output is not what you expect. Bonus? *Give us what the output **should** look like.*

Comment: *"TEST_A & folder "D1" has no date"* is row 3 of my data; *"TEST_B & Folder "Screen" has a date"* (though you currently are saying TEST_B) is row 4 of my data; since subject "B" meets both conditions, you say *"Remove all rows"*, which means remove all rows for subject B.

Comment: @PanDora, a side note: you have on your profile *'I have been harassed more on this site asking questions"*, and I understand your issue and see the discomfort. If I've offended or you've felt pressure, my apologies. I really am trying to clarify the question/issue and help you both (a) get resolution sooner, and (b) learn more techniques on what to include in questions in order to improve the likelihood of getting a fast and higher-quality answer. I understand your frustration. My "nagging" for clarity is because it really is difficult helping with the confusion I see here. Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans I have voted to delete this question. Feel free to do the same. I will be deleting my account here.  I do not know how to use this platform correctly because I get so many message not trying to understand my problem but instead tell me everything that I am doing wrong in asking the question.  Sometime I do not understand the problem enough to ask the question properly so I get attacked. Next time I will just hire some one to help me instead of wasting my time here

Comment: [1/n] That's certainly your choice, and I'm sad that you're so frustrated that this is the only way out for you. I know many "requests" (loosely speaking) asking to clarify or improve sample data are rather acerbic and harsh, and while I can be candid/curt at times, I am trying to soften my own requests and suggest to others how they can do the same, but it's just that, a suggestion from me. From my perspective, it can be really difficult to help somebody when the data is missing or not representative, but I really want to help.

Comment: [2/n] If we were in the same room, it would be a conversation, where I would ask a question about it, you would reply or clarify, and I might suggest a change to the data or function. The conversation would go back and forth until I know enough about the data and your intent and needs to be able to suggest an answer. However fluid a verbal conversation might be, doing so in comments is limited, so it is much more difficult. This is exacerbated by some askers (not you) posting questions as a specification expecting full compliance, not a welcome entry, so occasionally we are dulled a little.

Comment: [3/3] Bottom line, learning to ask questions succinctly with as much reproducibility as reasonable for the question is a skill that is improved with iterative interaction. A thick skin on the asker's part is particularly helpful, but ultimately the community can be various levels of curt, candid, and often acerbic in communicating requests, expectations, and unfortunately often communicating frustration over misunderstanding or impatience. I wish there were a better way. StackOverflow can fit a niche, but it is not without issues. Good luck.